# Is there a Socket6 0.23 module for Perl 5.14 in windows?

Tags: perl, sockets

I'm migrating a legacy perl project from Perl 5.8 to Perl 5.14 in Windows XP platform. Now I encounter a problem on a required Socket6 module.

The current Socket6 is requiring perl58.dll so it cannot be directly reused. I try to search Socket binary distributions for 5.14 however I only find linux versions, such as: http://pkgs.org/mageia-cauldron/mageia-core-release-x86_64/perl-Socket6-0.230.0-4.mga2.x86_64.rpm.html

I try to build the latest source code in Windows XP with 5.14 but since PL_sv_undef is not supported in Perl5.14 that some compilation error encounters so I cannot continue.

Would you help if there's existing binary distribution in XP or guidelines regarding how to build socket6 in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Socket6 is not necessary on 5.14: The Socket module (finally) has [proper built-in IPv6 support](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.14.0/pod/perldelta.pod#Improved_IPv6_support). If you don't need your code to work on older versions of perl, I'd recommend using that instead of Socket6. Otherwise, [Socket::GetAddrInfo](https://metacpan.org/module/Socket%3a%3aGetAddrInfo) may provide what you need.

Answer (score 0):

CPAN Tester Reports show it have been failing for Win32 build. You may try the cygwin build which seems to work.

http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/S/Socket6.html#Socket6-0.23